# undefined reference ___atomic_is_lock_free with Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: c++, xcode, stdatomic

I am running a code like this on Mac:

```
    #include <atomic>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <utility>
    #include <atomic>

    struct A { int a[100]; };
    struct B { int x, y; };
    int main()
    {
        std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << "std::atomic<A> is lock free? "
        << std::atomic<A>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n'
        << "std::atomic<B> is lock free? "
        << std::atomic<B>{}.is_lock_free() << '\n';
    }
```

the error message is :
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "___atomic_is_lock_free", referenced from:
      _main in testassembly.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

is_lock_free is part of c++ standard library, seem strange to me. do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I don't think it's dup. the question you referred to is a generic problem, but mine is specific about ___atomic_is_lock_free

Comment: There are thousands of reason for an undefined reference: That&#39;s exactly why we have a generic one. So that we&#39;re able to close every question about undefined references. Just what I think.

Comment: not exactly. most undefined reference are because we miss it in our code, but some of them are related with compiler or SDK, or OS. ___atomic_is_lock_free should be provided by C++ system library, that's the difference.

Comment: If you look, you'll see that the linked question also includes some information about missing system libraries.

Comment: I guess you're right in a way. :) Sorry

Comment: std::atomic<B>{}.is_lock_free() along is compilable, so i thinks it's sth with `int a[100];

Comment: @ExBen: Did you ever find the answer?

Comment: did you add -latomic to your linker flags?